# boto3 Request Entity Too Large when uploading file with size 6MB, even if multipart_thershold is much bigger than 6MB

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to save file to s3-compatible storage (to be precise, ceph)

Here is the code:

```
import boto3
import requests
from boto3.s3.transfer import TransferConfig


s3 = boto3.client('s3', endpoint_url='http://s3.example.com',
                  aws_access_key_id='VXBJDJDLSDHHSDL',
                  aws_secret_access_key='SDGHHSDHSDKsdhgsdgj123423bsdsdjSDHdhf')

content = requests.get('http://example.com').content

s3.upload_fileobj(Fileobj=io.BytesIO(content), Bucket=bucket, Key=f'{master_folder}/{folder}/{g.split("/")[-1]}', ExtraArgs={'ACL': 'public-read'},
Config=TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=9046456)
```

Content length of uploading data is 3722588, multipart threshold is bigger, but code fails with
`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (413) when calling the PutObject operation: Request Entity Too Large`
How to fix it?

I expect boto3 to use given config and upload files which size are less then multipart_threshold

Comment: `endpoint_url='http://s3.example.com'` - are you calling Amazon S3 or an S3-compatible object store e.g. MinIO?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary, I call S3-compatible object, ceph.

Comment: OK please add that to your question as it's important to know if you're calling Amazon S3 or something that just uses the S3 APIs and has its own config.

Comment: set `payload_signing_enabled` : Specifies whether to include an SHA-256 checksum with Amazon Signature Version 4 payloads. Valid settings are true or false.
For streaming uploads (UploadPart and PutObject) that use HTTPS and include a content-md5 header, this setting is disabled by default.